# What locale does VIM use for sorting and regular expressions?

Tags: vim, sorting, utf-8, locale

Suppose I have a file with the following content:

```
c
C
b
B
a
A
```

When I do `:%sort`, I get the following result:

```
A
B
C
a
b
c
```

When I do `:%!sort` (note the '!'), I get

```
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

I get the same behaviour with regular expressions, i.e.
[A-Z] inside VIM matches uppercase characters and not [aAbBcC...].

The output of "locale":

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The output of `:language` inside VIM:

```
Current language: 
"LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_NUMERIC=C;
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8"
```

According to ":language" vim should be using "utf8 sorting", but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From VIM 7.3 ':help sort'

```
The details about sorting depend on the library function used.  There is no
guarantee that sorting is "stable" or obeys the current locale.  You will have
to try it out.
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) I know that this is not really an answer to the main question that was asked, and (2) I don't have access to `vim` right now, so all I can be sure of is that this works for `vi`.  That said, you can get `vi` to do case-insensitive searches by typing `:set ignorecase` (or `:set ic` for short, or `:se ic` for shorter).  Use `:set noic` to revert to case-sensitive behavior.